# Writing data to file using PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to save json data to a file using AJAX and PHP but the resulting file is empty. Why is it not working?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var dataset = {"value1": 2, "value2": 1000};

$.ajax({
   url: 'save.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: dataset,
   success: function() {
      alert('Success');
   }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

save.php:

```
<?php 
$map=json_decode($_POST['json_string']);
$file = "test.json"; 
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $map);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: `$map=json_decode($_POST['json_string']);` you didn't post any `json_string`, nor any JSON to be decoded. `type: 'POST'` with default settings will send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request with the key->value pairs of your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wrong POST variable name. Firstly, send your AJAX request with:

```
data: { 
    json: dataset
    },
```

And then use:

```
$map = $_POST['json'];
```

Don't decode it since you want to save JSON string, not an array. If you want PHP representation, better use `var_export()`:

```
$map = var_export(json_decode($_POST['json'], true), true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, still not working. I replaced the AJAX request and the PHP code (using var_export). I get a NULL in the file.

Comment: Do a quick `die(var_dump($_POST));` to see what's inside and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

change this line `$map=json_decode($_POST['json_string']);` to `$map=json_decode($_POST['dataset']);`